# jQuery Deferred weirdness

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I am working on a small script implementing deferreds and ran across this little bit of code that isn't behaving as I would expect Javascript to.

```
var dfd = $.Deferred()
  , view  = $.get("filename.tmpl");

$.get("filename.json")
  .always(function (model) {
    dfd.resolve(model);
  });

$.when(view, dfd)
  .done(function (view, model) {
    // do stuff with view - even if there is no model
  });
```

And this works fine, but when I refactor to this it stops working:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred()
  , view  = $.get("filename.tmpl");

$.get("filename.json").always(dfd.resolve);

$.when(view, dfd)
  .done(function (view, model) {
    // do stuff with view - even if there is no model
  });
```

I don't see any reason that this shouldn't work. The function is expecting the first argument to be the model or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$.get("filename.json").always(dfd.resolve);
```

instead of this:

```
$.get("filename.json")
  .always(function (model) {
    dfd.resolve(model);
});
```

you will get a different object passed as the `this` pointer for the `resolve()` method.  The second will call it in the context of `dfd`.  The first will call it the context of the deferred object returned from your `$.get()` which is different.

It important to remember that when passing a callback `dfd.resolve` just gets a pointer to the method.  It does NOT set the context in which `resolve` will be called.  That is set internally to the `.always()` method.

Comment: Then, shouldn't it still work if I bind the `model` as the context for `dfd.resolve`? Like this: `model.always(dfd.resolve.bind(model));`.

Comment: To get the same result in the 2nd code snippet as in the first snippet, you would have to find to `dfd`, not to `model` like this: `$.get("filename.json").always(dfd.resolve.bind(dfd));` but I don't know why this is better than the first code snippet which makes it more clear what is happening.

Comment: Agreed. I was just waxing philosophical not proposing that it should be done that way. Thank you both for the help. I was too lazy this evening to dive that deep into why it was working the way it does.